# Gauss-Jordan elimination to solve without employing pivoting

Tags: gaussian-elimination

While reading the book Numerical Methods for Engineers by Steven Chapra and Raymond Canale, I came across a problem in Gauss-Jordan elimination. The problem says,

$$2x_1+x_2-x_3=1\\                    
5x_1+2x_2-2x_3=-4\\
3x_1+x_2+x_3=5$$

to solve this using Gauss-Jordan but without employing pivoting. So far I only know that in order to solve this I need to use pivot to make the 3 rows to contain only one 1.

What are the algorithm to solve this without pivoting?

Comment: Are LU decomposition and Gauss-Jordan Elimination same? I actually don't know their difference!

Comment: This will do. Can you please post your comments as answer ?

Comment: There is another question I found which says to solve a similar system of equations by LU decomposition without pivoting!!! Now I am confused, which is what!!!!

Comment: Weird!!! My book doesn't have any example 9.5 which uses Guss-Jordan without pivoting'

Comment: Mine is version 6. Example 9.5 is naive gauss eliminaiton !

Comment: 9.12 doesn't say to do it without pivoting!